# Flex content width not calculated correctly inside a position: fixed container in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox, bootstrap-4, internet-explorer-11

I'm building a custom tooltip that uses `position: fixed` and a dynamic `top` and `left` to follow your mouse cursor around. The tooltip has a relatively complex layout built with flexbox. I'm having an issue with IE11 (which otherwise supports flexbox just fine using autoprefixer) where the width of the tooltip is getting collapsed down as if it had no content.

I made a Codepen stripping out all my implementation details except for the most basic Bootstrap layout and CSS, and the issue is still present. You can see it in action here https://codepen.io/ryangiglio/pen/xajLJr. Here is the code:

HTML

```
<!-- Regular content -->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 text-center">
      Column
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 text-center">
      Column
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 text-center">
      Column
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Tooltip content -->
<div class="custom-tooltip">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 text-center">
        Tooltip Title
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 text-center">
        Column
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 text-center">
        Column
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 text-center">
        Column
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.custom-tooltip {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px black;
}
```

This is how it looks in Chrome

[image: Chrome]

And how it looks in IE11

[image: IE11]

Comment: full page mode works ine IE11 , debug mode depends on: if your logged in, not expired , you(or I) have a  pro account or not ...

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided was not valid cause I'm not a pro member.

On another note, I'm not sure, but it could be that when you set the box shadow property it changed the display, but I'm not sure and wanted to test that theory out but couldn't.
--- Edited
Try the below code you have to also make sure you correctly set the flex-direction property.

```
div.custom-tooltip{ 
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction:column; 
} 
div.row{ 
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction:row; 
}
```

---

--- EDITED ANSWER ---

```
/* 
I set the tooltip box containers 
width to be a percentage, I don't
know if this a documented issue 
with ie11 or not, where ie 11
doesn't realize that flex is being 
used on a fixed element and goes with
default values for width.  

*/
div[data-tooltip-boxwidth="300"] {
 width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: div.custom-tooltip{ 
    display: flex;
      flex-direction:column;
    }
    div.row{ 
    display: flex;
      flex-direction:row;
    }

Comment: Sorry, I updated the link. It's not the box-shadow, unfortunately.

Comment: Sad day, :( ... anyways I would try to manually set the width of the tooltip box like this =>
https://codepen.io/kipomaha/pen/JaZNbM  
Comments left in css

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I didn't care enough about the underlying issue here to spend too much more time solving it, so I ended up hard-coding a width on the `.custom-tooltip` class which solved the problem enough for me to ship it.